# Question about this proof of the orientability of tangent bundle

Tags: differential-geometry, manifolds, smooth-manifolds

I have a question about this proof given here:

[image]

Is it possible that the det(A) might be identically 0? The solution is implying this is impossible but doesn't say why.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This follows from the definition of a differentiable manifold: as in any atlas of any differentiable manifold, the overlap map $\Phi$ is a diffeomorphism between its domain and range, and hence each of its Jacobian matrices $A(u) = (A_{ij}(u))$ is invertible.